# Error message when rapidly trying to flag comments is incorrect

Tags: bug, comment-flags, wording

If one flags comments in rapid succesion one could be faced by this error message:

[image: screenshot of error stating: "You may only attempt to flag this comment every 3 seconds."]

> You may only attempt to flag this comment every 3 seconds.

This happens regardless of the previous comment one opened the flag dialogue on. It can either be the same comment, or a different comment. The resulting error message is the same. Hence the wording should be updated to state:

> "You may only attempt to flag **a** comment every 3 seconds."

Seeing that that is the actual behavious that is enforced.